# Can't understand meteor user accounts

Tags: meteor

I could write pages about the questions I have surrounding user accounts. I've been putting off simply asking for help because there's obviously something core that I'm missing here, something that's been so thoroughly explained in the documentation for the layperson that it'd even be offensive to ask.

```
Template.login.foo = function(){
        return Meteor.users();
      }; 

        <h4>Hello</h>
        <ul>{{#each foo}}
        <li>{{createdAt}}</li>
        {{/each}}
        </ul>
```

I have autopublish on for now. I apologize if I'm missing something obvious here, I'm just starting out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a function at `return Meteor.users()`. If you want to return all the users data you have to access the `Meteor.users` [collection](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_users) with a `find` query:

```
return Meteor.users.find({});
```